# Async calls per each array element and wait for completion

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I found many similar questions but none with the same purpose (or maybe i just didnt understand? Can be that as well).

I've an array of elements, a function A that performs an async operation with an element and returns a promise, and the function B i'm working on which should call A for each array element, and return a promise once all the A calls have been completed. How can i do that?
Relevant code:

```
var img = [];
img[0] = "http://www.something.com/picture0.jpg";
img[1] = "http://www.something.com/picture1.jpg";
img[2] = "http://www.something.com/picture2.jpg";
function ask(img)
    {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
        if(something)
            {resolve("test");}
        else
            {reject("test");}
        }
    }
function analyze_all(img)
    {
    for(var i in img)
        {
        ask(img[i])
        .then((res) => 
            {
            ???
            })
        .catch((err) =>
            {
            ???
            });
        }
    return ???
    }
```

I thought about pushing all results to a list, like that:

```
function analyze_all(img)
    {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i in img)
        {
        ask(img[i])
        .then((res) => 
            {
            ret.push({image: img[i], data: res});
            })
        .catch((err) =>
            {
            ret.push({image: img[i], error: err});
            });
        }
    return ???
    }
```

But then how do i know when will all the async calls be completed?
Please help!

---

Solved. As addition, if someone has similar needs and wants to have all the "return" values whether they're resolves or rejects, i suggest checking the following link:
https://nmaggioni.xyz/2016/10/13/Avoiding-Promise-all-fail-fast-behavior/

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to turn a list of promises into a promise that resolves to a list.

Comment: I'm not understanding, the list must contain the Promise returned by the function call or the resolved value?

Comment: The promise that somewhen resolves to the value you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, use `Promise.all`:

```
function analyze_all(img) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i in img) {
        ret.push( 
          ask(img[i]).then((res) => {
            // something
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // something
          })
        )
    }
    return Promise.all(ret);
}
```

Comment: @barnack no, it is not?

Comment: ok i just need time to understand the concept and how to handle the results, thanks for the answer!